# Understanding the Polyhedral Model

Tags: optimization, arrays, iteration

I am wondering at a high level the mathematics of the [Polyhedral Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model).

> The polyhedral model (also called the polytope method) is a mathematical framework for programs that perform large numbers of operations -- too large to be explicitly enumerated -- thereby requiring a compact representation. The polyhedral method treats each loop iteration within nested loops as **lattice points** inside mathematical objects called **polyhedra**, performs **affine transformations** or more general non-affine transformations such as tiling on the polytopes, and then converts the transformed polytopes into equivalent, but optimized (depending on targeted optimization goal), loop nests through polyhedra scanning.

I would like to understand the basic mathematical components of this but am having difficulty with the notation.

Specifically wondering what is going on in Figure 1 below. That is, where the **polyhedra**, **lattice points**, and **affine transformations** are, and how to represent/define them with mathematical notation. For instance, I haven't seen anything yet saying "a polyhedron from a loop is a tuple $p = (R, L, A)$ where $R$ is a set of loops, $L$ is a lattice and $A$ is a set of affine transformations, ...". Looking for the definitions of these 3 things and their relationship, as well as the relation between the loop variables and the *what looks like* is a matrix equation in the figure.

[image]

Figure (1) -^.

[image]

Figure (2) -^.

Comment: Try this: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/60c8/54d27c9cf71a88a733acf190b9ff0fcb2872.pdf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you for that link, really good resource. The only thing left is understanding the matrices on page 5 section "2.3 The Source Polytope". Any help with that would be greatly appreciated. (similar to the matrices on the first diagram bottom left). Don't know where those numbers all come from.

Comment: I suggest reviewing linear algebra.